# How can you delete a BizTalk receive port with a slash in the name using the PowerShell provider?

Tags: powershell, biztalk, biztalk-ps1-provider

How can you delete a receive port when the name contains a slash?

I've got a receive port with a slash in its name, e.g. something like ... TestReceivePort/Service

When I try `Remove-Item -Path "TestReceivePort/Service"`, I get an error that ...

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find 
              path BTS:\Applications\TestApp\Receive Ports\TestReceivePort\Service
```

Tried `-LiteralPath`, tried single quotes

Comment: Hmm...and neither the escape char setting a variable works.

Comment: @boatseller I ended up using the ExplorerOM RemoveReceivePort method

Comment: You should write up a quick answer with your code and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Bitmask beat me to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help:

```
[void] [System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM")
$server = "."
$connectionString = "SERVER=" + $server + ";DATABASE=BizTalkMgmtDb;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$Catalog = New-Object Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer
$Catalog.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$rcvLocation =  $Catalog.ReceivePorts | Where {$_.Name = 'rcvLocation/withSlash'}
$Catalog.RemoveReceivePort($rcvLocation)
$Catalog.SaveChanges()
```